# Pass parameter to Angularjs controller function from directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a AngularJs directive that creates a property and callback function on its isolated scope:

```
.directive('testButton', [function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    controller: 'TestDirectiveController as vmDirective',
    scope: {     
        myCallBack:'&myCallBack',
        myVariable: '=myVariable'
    },
    template: function (element, attrs) {
        return '<button data-ng-click="vmDirective.onButtonClicked(2)">Set myVariable = 2</button>';
    }
};}])
```

In the directive a button gets clicked and it executes the `onButtonClicked` function. This then sets a scope variable and calls the `$scope.myCallBack` function.

The callBack function gets executed and does the following:
`console.log($scope.linkedVariable);`

The problem is the `$scope.linkedVariable` has not yet been updated and at that stage the `$scope.linkedVariable` is still the previous value.

When I wrap the above code in a `setTimeout` the correct value is retrieved: `setTimeout(function(){console.log($scope.linkedVariable)}, 2000);`

**My Question** is, how to properly pass the value to the `onCallBack` function.

Please see full code example below:

```
   angular.module('application',[])

   .directive('testButton', [function () {
      return {
         restrict: 'A',
         controller: 'TestDirectiveController as vmDirective',
         scope: {     
              myCallBack:'&myCallBack',
              myVariable: '=myVariable'
         },
         template: function (element, attrs) {
            return '<button data-ng-click="vmDirective.onButtonClicked(2)">Set myVariable = 2</button>';
         }
       };
    }])

  .controller("TestDirectiveController", ['$scope', function($scope){
       var self = this;
       self.onButtonClicked = function(value){
          $scope.myVariable = value;
          $scope.myCallBack();
       };
   }])

  .controller("TestController", ['$scope', function($scope){
      var self = this;
      $scope.linkedVariable = null;

      self.onCallBack = function(){
      console.log($scope.linkedVariable);
      setTimeout(function(){console.log($scope.linkedVariable)}, 2000);
    };
 }])
```

HTML:

```
<div data-ng-controller="TestController as vm">
   <div data-test-button="" data-my-call-back="vm.onCallBack()" data-my-variable="linkedVariable"></div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ff5ck0da/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a more acceptable/correct way of overcoming my problem thanks to http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-3-isolate-scope-and-function-parameters.

Instead of accessing the `$scope.linkedVariable` in the controller, I now accept the value as a parameter to the function.

To get this to work I had to change the function declaration in the HTML to:

`data-my-call-back="vm.onCallBack"`

The controller function declaration:

```
self.onCallBack = function(myVariable){
    console.log(myVariable);        
};
```

the directive can then call the function like:

```
self.onButtonClicked = function(value){        
    $scope.myCallBack()(value);
};
```

Please see a updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ff5ck0da/9/

Answer (score 0):

You can even change the settimeout to

```
setTimeout(function(){console.log($scope.linkedVariable)}, 0);
```

this will push the resolution of the variable to the bottom of the async stack.
And thus evaluate after the angular digest loop is done ( in essence the variable value is set)

If you dont want to use settimeout you can use this:

```
self.onCallBack = function(){
        var accessor = $parse($scope.linkedVariable);
        $scope.value = angular.copy(accessor($scope.$parent));
        console.log($scope.linkedVariable);
};
```

here you are essentially telling angular to not use a copy but the actual parent variable.

Comment: I would like not to use a `setTimeout` as it seems a bit hacky.

Comment: This seems a bit elaborate for something so trivial? Is there not a more built in way?

Comment: I am afraid not. As long as you stay in your directive controller all is wel. But angular starts to make copies between controllers and those need a digest cycle to update. your callback is being triggered before that is done so your variable is not set at that point. the timeout hack forces it to be evaluated last after the digest is done. and the second workaround uses the same variable instead of a copy to circumvent the digest.

Comment: I found a more acceptable/correct way of doing it, please see my answer below