# Assign scope function with param from controller to var in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, directive

Maybe the title isn't perfect - but I'm explaining shortly:

In my `HTML` I'm using `ng-click` directive: 
(I'm using few `ng-clicks` directives within my HTML code with different parameters (like 'main', 'action', 'more', etc..)

```
ng-click="clickMe('main')"
```

I have a controller to get the `id` - `'main'`:

```
.controller('clickCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.clickMe= function (id) {
        console.log("button: " + id);
    }
}]);
```

I want to assign the `$scope.clickMe` in my directive link function and get the passed `id` value :

```
.directive('clickDir', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var click = scope.clickMe;

            click = function(id) {      //can I get the "id" here from controller also? 
                //some stuff
            }
    }}});
```

But it isn't working, could you help me?

**EDIT**

Some code from my HTML:

```
<div class="my-navbar">
    <ul click-dir>
        <li>
            <a ng-click="clickMe('main')" href="..." class="..."></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="action-navbar">
    <ul click-dir>
        <li ng-repeat="..."> //a lot of <li> generated by ng-repeat
            <a ng-click="clickMe('actions')" href="..." class="..."></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="search-navbar">
    <ul click-dir>
        <li ng-repeat="..."> //a lot of <li> generated by ng-repeat
            <a ng-click="clickMe('search')" href="..." class="..."></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to get the `id` parameters from `ng-click` in the `click-dir` directive because I want to make some DOM manipulation.

Comment: In your directive, you assign `scope.clickMe` to `click`, then assign the anonymous function to `click`, why?

Comment: Do you want to invoke the controller's function from the directive and pass in the value to the controller function?

Comment: @Joy - maybe I'm doing something wrong, I just want to get the "id", but I don't know how to do it

Comment: How does your HTML look like? What exactly are you trying to achieve with the combination of `ng-click` and the custom directive? Maybe what you really want is to handle the click event in your directive...?

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt - I want to invoke the controller's function from the directive and also get an `id`, I don't know that you understand me correctly

Comment: @pdenes - yes, I want to handle the click event in my directive (like in the controller) - but I don't know how to make it **edit** I'm updating my question with more HTML

Comment: maybe check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31181668/angularjs-directive-pass-parameter-to-controller-function/31183125#31183125 it might point you into the right direction.

Comment: I updated my question with some more HTML

Comment: What else does your `clickDir` directive do?

Comment: Do you actually want to handle the click event from _both_ places, so both from the controller and the directive, independently of each other, but at the same time, get hold of the parameter to the `ng-click` handler in your directive? So would this just be a shortcut for something like `<a ng-click="clickMe('main')" click-dir="main">` ?

Comment: @pdenes `clickDir` is making some DOM manipulations (adding/removing classes) - something like here http://digitalfondue.ch/df-tab-menu/ when you decrease the width of the page

Comment: @pdenes - I'm thinking how to resolve this problem, but the idea is: when you click the `clickMe('main')` I want to get this event handler and its parameter in directive . (I don't need the controller indeed, but  it helps me with the handling the `clickMe` event - I didn't find the solution without the controller yet)

Comment: @vvdfg_mine: Then I think what you need is a variation of the answer from Paul Boutes: pass on the event handler from the controller using `&` and also pass on the `id` parameter, _but separately_: `<a click-dir="main" click="click">`. Add `clickDir: '@'` to your scope definition, and then in the link function: `element.on('click', function() { scope.click()(scope.clickDir); })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to handle the click event in your directive, then you can do it directly, without using `ng-click`. Something like this:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    // get "id" from attrs or declare it in your directive config in scope
    element.on('click', function() {
        // use "id" here...
    });
}
```

If the "id" parameter is a simple string, you could do this:

```
scope: {
    clickDir: '@'
},
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    element.on('click', function() {
        // use scope.clickDir here...
    });
}
```

And the HTML would simply become:

```
<a click-dir='main'>...</a>
```

(Again, assuming you don't actually need to combine your controller/outer scope and the directive, other than passing the constant "id" values from the HTML.)

Comment: I don't think this is the angular way.

Comment: @Tjaart van der Walt: You may be right, it depends on what exactly we want to achieve here... I was thinking about `clickDir` being a directive that does some other stuff and also needs to handle click events. In that case I can see no point in involving `ng-click` and another controller. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Okay, finally I made it works, I think it's the best and simplest solution. Big thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **&** angular binding, which allows the directive's isolate scope to pass values into the parent scope, for evaluation in the expression defined in the attribute, in our example we defined **click** attribute.

So you can define your function into your Controller, and bind her to your directive.

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope) {

  $scope.click = function(id){
    console.log('button : ' + id)
  }


}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();
```

**Directive**

```
(function(){

  function clickDir() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
          //Use '&' binding to evaluate expression
          click: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
          //Listen for click event
          element.on('click', function(){
            //Call click controller function
            scope.click();
          });
        }
    };
  }

angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('clickDir', clickDir);


})();
```

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

    <button type="button" click-dir click="click('tata')">button</button>
    <button type="button" click-dir click="click('toto')">button2</button>
    <button type="button" click-dir click="click('titi')">button3</button>


  </body>
```